Hollywood teen comedy movie - virgin on a ship
Please identify a movie, all I remember is just some parts of the plot.
I don't remember much, but I'll tell you what I do remember and hopefully someone will recall the name of the movie or the actors who play in it. 
So, it's a Hollywood teenage comedy movie, the characters are on a big ship/boat and there's a young man (main character) who is virgin and wants to have sex (obviously). He is the only virgin on a ship and he doesn't like being one very much.
I also remember one scene: This virgin is in a room with a woman who wears a big (old-fashioned, you know from the 18-19th centuries, like Cinderella's dress) dress and suddenly someone enters the room. The virgin gets under the woman's dress and the guest can't notice him. I think this virgin was wearing a fake mustache during this scene. Probably they were on some costume party before because the timeline is in the 20th or 21st century. 
And I remember the ending: This woman wants to have sex with all men on the ship, so there's a very long queue of men near her room. There's also some bloopers after the credits. I thought that the virgin was played by Jack Black (or Jason Biggs) but I think I'm mistaken. Also, as I recall the main character can't get a girl during the whole movie and stays the vrigin.

Sounds like Dorm Daze 2 from 2006 about a bunch of horny students wrecking havoc on a cruise ship. You can see the scene you've mentioned (the virgin who's trying to get laid hides under a woman's dress while wearing a fake moustache) in the trailer at minute 2:12:



